# Why private members of a PHP Trait are accessible from a PHP class?

Tags: php, traits

I wondered why it is possible to access to the private properties and methods of a PHP Trait in a class that uses that Trait.

Here is my PHP Trait: `BulkMessageMembers.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait BulkMessageMembers
{
    private string $endpoint;
    private string $text;
    private array $phone_numbers;
    private string $server_response;

    public bool $sms_status = false;
    public int $user_id;
}
```

And my PHP class (This is only a portion of code.) `SMSJsonBulkMessageService.php` that uses my Trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Interfaces\SMSGateway;
use App\Models\Balance;
use App\Models\Message;
use App\Models\MessageSetting;
use App\Models\UserMessageSetting;
use App\Traits\BulkMessageMembers;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class SMSJsonBulkMessageService implements SMSGateway
{
   use BulkMessageMembers;

   public function __construct(
       private readonly UserMessageSetting $preference,
       private readonly Collection $messages, private readonly MessageSetting $setting
   )
   {
       $this->prepare();
   }

   private function prepare(): void
   {
       $this->endpoint = $this->preference->messageProvider->bulk_endpoint;

       $this->messages->each(function ($message) {

           $this->phone_numbers[] = sprintf('243%d', $message->phone_number);
       });

       $this->text = $this->messages->first()->description;
   }


   /**
    * @throws ConnectException
    * @return void
    */
   public function send(): void
   {
       //
   }

   public function update(): void
   {
       //
   }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why from my PHP class I access the private properties of a Trait? I know trait is not a class per se, but its main interest is to reduce some limitations of single inheritance by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in several independent classes living in different class hierarchies.

Need clarification please.

Comment: My question is why would you not expect them to be accessible? Traits are not classes and using traits is not inheritance so the behaviour should not be anchored on those constructs

Comment: @apokryfos There may be "horizontal reuse" mechanisms in other languages which _do_ allow for functionality to be hidden / encapsulated in the reusable unit; the "flattening" is a design decision, not an inevitable consequence of horizontal reuse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common explanation of traits is that they are "compiler-assisted copy-and-paste": when you incorporate a trait into a concrete class, the contents of that trait are inserted into the class definition as though you had written them by hand.

No distinction is maintained between members inserted by the trait, and members written directly in the class definition; and no relationship is maintained between the class and the trait the members were copied from. In some cases, there are additional constraints checked by the compiler, or renaming that is performed as part of the `use` statement, but in the simple case, it is exactly as though you had copied the code from one file to the other.

In your case, the code that is compiled is essentially this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Interfaces\SMSGateway;
use App\Models\Balance;
use App\Models\Message;
use App\Models\MessageSetting;
use App\Models\UserMessageSetting;
use App\Traits\BulkMessageMembers;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class SMSJsonBulkMessageService implements SMSGateway
{
   private string $endpoint;
   private string $text;
   private array $phone_numbers;
   private string $server_response;

   public bool $sms_status = false;
   public int $user_id;

   public function __construct(
       private readonly UserMessageSetting $preference,
       private readonly Collection $messages, private readonly MessageSetting $setting
   )
   {
       $this->prepare();
   }

   private function prepare(): void
   {
       $this->endpoint = $this->preference->messageProvider->bulk_endpoint;

       $this->messages->each(function ($message) {

           $this->phone_numbers[] = sprintf('243%d', $message->phone_number);
       });

       $this->text = $this->messages->first()->description;
   }


   /**
    * @throws ConnectException
    * @return void
    */
   public function send(): void
   {
       //
   }

   public function update(): void
   {
       //
   }
}
```

Looking at that code, it should be no surprise that the `prepare` method has access to `$this->phone_numbers`.

Answer (score 3):

Beyond @IMSoP's great answer, I think quoting the [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/traits#the_flattening_property) that introduced the feature brings clarity, specifically the last sentence:

> **The Flattening Property**
>
> As already mentioned, multiple inheritance and Mixins are complex mechanisms. Traits are an alternative which have been designed to impose no additional semantics on classes. Traits are only entities of the literal code written in your source files. There is no notion about Traits at runtime. They are used to group methods and reuse code and are totally flattened into the classes composed from them. It is almost like a language supported and failsafe copy'n'paste mechanism to build classes.